# ignoring case in libpcre with c

Tags: c, pcre

How do I ignore case when using pcre_compile and pcre_exec?

```
pcre_exec(
    pcre_compile(pattern,0,&error,&erroroffset,0),
    0, string, strlen(string), 0, 0, ovector, sizeof(ovector));
```

what option do i use and where do i specify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `PCRE_CASELESS` in the second argument to `pcre_compile`, like this:

```
pcre_compile(pattern, PCRE_CASELESS, ...
```

(Note that you're leaking memory there - you need to call `pcre_free` on the object returned by `pcre_compile`.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `PCRE_CASELESS` flag in the pcre_compile.

Example:

```
  pcre_compile(
    pattern,              /* the pattern */
    PCRE_CASELESS|PCRE_MULTILINE,                    /* default options */
    &error,               /* for error message */
    &erroffset,           /* for error offset */
    NULL);                /* use default character tables */
```